# jQuery - animate not css value, but just global variable in JS

Tags: jquery, flash, jquery-animate

Is there some way to use jQuery.animate to animate global variables in JS?
I mean something like this:

var FlashPlayerVolume = 0.0;

$jQuery.Animate( {FlashPlayerVolume: 1.0}, 200 );

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Does'nt really sound like a good idea, but to answer the question, yes you can animate anything by using the built in $.fx.step method.

Easiest way to do that is to just animate some arbitrary value on a hidden element or something, and do this:

```
var FlashPlayerVolume = 0.0;

$('div').css('font-size', 0.0).animate({ fontSize: 1.0 }, {
    duration: 3000,
    step: function(now, fx) { 
        FlashPlayerVolume = now;
        console.log(FlashPlayerVolume);
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/MhysR/)
    ​

Comment: Yep, i did it, but using opacity param. And it work great, but only if browser tab/window are visible. I need something to work even if tab/window is hidden. (For example, you minimize window and then music getting volume down.)

Comment: Not sure that's even possible with javascript, and if it is I don't know how. Usually javascripts timer functions will stop when the browser/tab is minimized, but anything is possible, so there surely is  a way to do this aswell.

Comment: Ok im going to do my own animation effect here:

    $j.fx.step.volume = function(fx) {
  var dom_id = $j(fx.elem).attr("id");
  window.player.bubbles[dom_id].volume = fx.now;
  
  console.log( window.player.bubbles[dom_id].volume );
 }
It work if starts with 0 and go to 1. Like here (initial volume is 0):

    $j("#bg_sound_mp3").animate( {volume: 1}, 1000 );

But from 1 to 0 dont work. (initial volume is 1):

    $j("#bg_sound_mp3").animate( {volume: 0}, 1000 );

jQuery didnt know the initial value, always starts from 0 thats why from 1 to 0 dont work jQuery see from 0 to 0 How can I fix it?

Comment: You can set the fx.start and fx.end values, don't remember exactly how to do it, but it is possible to set your own values when extending the fx.step function with your own methods, as I've done it myself some time ago with some CSS3 animations.

Comment: For the code to not affect every div, the selector should look like `$('<div/>')` instead of `$('div')`

Comment: @HDog - That does'nt select anything, it creates a new `div` !

Comment: I like this solution, I used it to animate the "garage door" effect through a 110 degree arc on my [portfolio](http://www.hughanderson.com/#portfolio) of my site.  On a big site I can't use a selector like `$('div')` or every div on the whole site will animate.  The `$('<div/>')` selector just gives me an isolated place to perform an arbitrary animation. `$('<div/>').css('font-size', 110.0).animate({fontSize:0.0}, {
                duration:700,
                step:function(now, fx) {
                    portBox.css(cssTransform, 'rotateX(' + -now + 'deg)');
                }
            });`